# OpenLayers 5 - Highlight feature on select

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have a feature that has a custom style (color).  When I click on it, it does not highlight.  However, if I edit the code by commenting out the 
 `myFeature.setStyle(myStyle)` call it highlights as expected.

Is there a way to force it to highlight when a style already exists for the feature?

Code sample:

```
const myFill = new Fill();
myFill.setColor('rgba(100,100,200,0.60)');
const myStyle = new Style({myFill});
const myFeature = new Feature(someObject);
myFeature.setStyle(myStyle);
mySource.addFeature(myFeature);

//...
const select = new Select({condition:click});
map.addInteraction(select);
```

I tried adding a style to the Select but no luck.

```
const select = new Select({condition:click, style: myHighlightStyle});
```

Comment: A select style won't override a feature style, but it will override a layer style so it's best to style your features via a style function on the layer.

Comment: I see that works, thanks! However, I have many different Features within a layer each with their own color. Is there a way to account for this?

Comment: As long as there's a way to associate the feature with the color it can be done via a style function, similar to this question perhaps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930198/how-to-add-many-markers-with-custom-text-to-openlayers-5

Comment: See also this example of an extensive style function: https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js